# Go 'present' on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, go

So I'm new to deploying servers to Heroku, I wen't through a small [tutorial](https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html) on how to deploy a go app to Heroku. I've been working with the `present` package for presentations in html5 slides. I want to add my slides to Heroku so I can access them from any computer. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this to work.

I know that the `present` binary is in the bin folder and I have my .slide markdown textfile in my `$GOPATH/src` folder. How can I deploy this to Heroku?

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `present` binary and your slides into some directory. `git init` a new branch. Then add a `Procfile` with the contents:

```
web: present --param whatever
```

Then just clone the buildpack:

```
heroku create -b https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
```

Commit and push to `heroku master`. You're done.

I got all this from http://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html

Comment: Very interesting.  I came upon this tutorial while trying to figure out how to use Heroku, but I don't think I tried this approach.  I posted on Reddit and I found another approach... using talks.godoc.org.  Unfortunately I don't have the time to try your approach at the time, but I will try at the beginning of May.. really busy with work at the time, but talks.godoc.org works! :)